# Issues with running a bash with an RVM environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, deployment, rvm

I am using whiskey_disk in order to handle deployments. This isn't a whiskey_disk issue, but what it does is run a post deploy script after it finishes cloning from git into the project destination directory. The script I'm trying to deploy is to invoke a `bundle install` and looks a little something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
if [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then
  source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
elif [[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then
  source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
else
  printf "ERROR: An RVM installation was not found.\n"
fi

export PATH=/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin

echo "["`hostname`"] Installing the bundle..."
bundle install --binstubs --local --path ../shared/bundle --deployment --without development test console replication|grep -vi using
```

That fails, and is not able to find `bundle` or `rake`, even though it's clearly setup in my `$PATH` above:

```
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 90 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'rake' (>= 0) among 90 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Thought I initialized the environment above fine in the beginning of the script and by additionally setting my PATH which you could see is seen fine with an interactive shell:

```
[ec2-user@ip-1 ~]$ which bundle
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/bundle
[ec2-user@ip-1 ~]$ which rake
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/rake
```

Any suggestions on what else could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RVM works by changing 3 environment variables (the minimal set), it is not enough to change just the `PATH`, you would also need to change `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH`.

The simplest would be to replace this line:

```
export PATH=...
```

with:

```
rvm use 2.0.0
```

then RVM does the environment loading and all should work fine.